# How to add List view item into dataset in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, fastreport

i am developing invoicing system

in my application there is a listview, a fastreport, button..
when press the the button the report should show the all item in the report
can anyone provide best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

From example PrintStringList from FastReport's Demos folder:

```
var
  Button1: TButton;
  StringDS: TfrxUserDataSet;
  frxReport1: TfrxReport;
  StringList: TStringList;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringDS.RangeEnd := reCount;
  StringDS.RangeEndCount := StringList.Count;
  frxReport1.ShowReport;
end;

procedure TForm1.frxReport1GetValue(const VarName: String; var Value: Variant);
begin
  if AnsiCompareText(VarName, 'element') = 0 then
    Value := StringList[StringDS.RecNo];
end;
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of those demos in the answer? It would make your answer stand alone. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing