# Printing listview items using fastreport in Delphi

Tags: delphi, fastreport, delphi-xe8

I am looking for a simple example or a reference to print items from a listview using fastreport. For example: I have a listview that has three columns: id, name and marks. The listview has n number items each containing id, name and  marks of individual students. I need to print the whole listview using fastreport in a tabular format. I googled but couldn't find an exact sample for my scope. Similarly, I couldn't find any documentation regarding this in fastreport demo. I am using Delphi XE8 with default installed fastreport version.

Comment: You should use `frxUserDataSet`. I don't know whether DelphiXE8 installation has `fastreport..\demo` folder. If there is see PrintStringList demo.

Comment: It isn't there. I did search for such question in SO. Btw I am new in using reporting tool.

Comment: @ValMarinov I found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535533/how-to-add-list-view-item-into-dataset-in-delphi

But the answer didn't seem to be clear to me.

Comment: Ок. I will try to write a brief "demo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For demonstration purposes.

Place on the form the following components:

- TButton;
- TListView;
- frxReport;
- frxUserDataSet;

Double click on frxReport. In the Fastreport designer do

insert ReportTitle, MasterData and PageFooter bands.

Press `Report => Data` menu items. Check `frxUserDataSet` check box and press `OK` button.

Assign MasterData band with `frxUserDataSet` as double click on MasterData band and select frxUserDataSet, then press 'OK' button.

In MasterData band insert `Text object` (Memo).
In Memo write `[element]`.

Designer should look like this :

[image]

Now we can write some code :

```
procedure TForm8.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Li : TlistItem;
begin
  // Just to fill some data in ListView 
  for I := 1 to 10 do
   begin
    Li := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LI.Caption := 'Col ' + IntToStr(i);
   end;

end;
```

In frxReport1 **OnGetValue** event write for example :

```
procedure TForm8.frxReport1GetValue(const VarName: string; var Value: Variant);
begin
  if CompareText(VarName, 'element') = 0 then
    Value := ListView1.Items[frxUserDataSet1.RecNo].Caption;
end;
```

And now print data

```
procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frxUserDataSet1.RangeEnd := reCount;
  frxUserDataSet1.RangeEndCount := ListView1.Items.Count;
  frxReport1.ShowReport();
end;
```

The result after Button1 is pressed:

[image]

*Note : In this answer is used part of FastReport  PrintStringList demo.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Yeah, it works as required.